# WPF: Prevent Combobox from Swallowing Keydown Event

Tags: wpf, events

So I have a window that handles the `KeyDown` event. Everything works as expected except under two conditions:

1. The up / down arrow keys are pressed and
2. A combo box on the window has more than one item.

Even if I've never clicked on the combo box it doesn't seem to matter. The `SelectionChanged` event on the combobox fires before the *Window* even fires its `KeyDown` event. This seems highly counter-intuitive to me.

I don't know enough about WPF event propagation to even know where to start looking for a solution. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should subscribe to `PreviewKeyDown` event instead.